# Can I use packages written for .NET Framework in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I'm studying C# 7.1 and .NET Core 2.0 - Modern Cross-Platform Development Third Edition written by Mark J. Price(by the way, great book), and I don't understand, as I wrote above, if I can use packages written for .NET Framework in .NET Standard 2.0.

Every help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you talking about *referencing* a .NET Framework assembly from a .NET Standard 2.0 assembly or the other way around?

Comment: Yes, I mean referencing a .NET Framework assembly from a .NET Standard 2.0 assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, .NET Standard 2.0 supports .NET core 2.0 libraries as well as .NET framework libraries up to version 4.6.1.

For more info take a look at the table available on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard.